# updated table and related table in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

In Laravel I have relation:

```
 class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'street', 'city', 'post_code', 'country', 'state',
    ];

    public function companies() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Company');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'name',  'nip', 'email', 'phone', 'address_id'
    ];

    public function address() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');
    }
}
```

---

and in CompaniesController.php I want to do update tables. My code looks like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
  Company::where('id', $id)->update([
          'name' => $request->name,
          'email' => $request->email,
          'phone' => $request->phone,
          'nip' => $request->nip,
        ]);
}
```

How to also update the address associated with this company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID is your primary key, you should use `find` instead of `where`, as the former will guarantee that you only retrieve one row.

You can then query the relationship of your Company model, using the following code:

```
$company = Company::find($id);
$company->update([
      'name' => $request->name,
      'email' => $request->email,
      'phone' => $request->phone,
      'nip' => $request->nip,
]);
$company->address()->update([
    'street' => 'street value',
    'city' => 'city value',
    'post_code' => 'post_code value',
    'country' => 'country value',
    'state' => 'state value',
]);
```

Please refer to the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Comment: Ok, thank, but I have a mistake:

"FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function address() on boolean". 

Is my relationship bad?

Comment: No. It was a mistake of mine, seems like update returns a boolean whether or not the update succeeded and not the model itself. I changed my code.