# Indirect modification of overloaded property Laravel Patch

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I get error 500 ( Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Example::$exampleName has no effect )
on my update method, and I am not sure why.

```
public function update(Request $request, Example $example)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'account_name' => 'required|string',
        'name'=> 'nullable|string',
        'name_type' =>'nullable|integer',
    ]);
    $example->account_name = $data['account_name'];
    $example->exampleName->name = $data['name'];
    $example->exampleName->name_type = $data['name_type'];

    $example->push(); 
    return response($example,200);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Dossier::$program has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624156/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-app-dossierprogram-has-no-effect)

Comment: I tried something similar, like in your url, but I get the same error.

Comment: You stated it in the comments below, but if `$example->exampleName` is `null`, you can't set `->name` on it. When `$example->exampleName` doesn't exist, you need to initialize it before you try to set properties, and you should never assume something exists in your code before trying to access/modify it. A simple `if($example->exampleName){ ... }` around the modifications should work.

Comment: You'r right. But if is not exist, I want to create it. I fount something on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713760/updated-table-and-related-table-in-laravel , and I write updateOrCreate for $example->exampleName, nothing yet, but I think that I am close.

Comment: Once again, if `$example->exampleName` is `null`, you won't be able to call a method on it (for example `updateOrCreate()`). I'll post an approach below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `$example->exampleName` can be `null`, so accessing/modifying properties, or calling methods is not allowed. Need to rethink the logic here. For example:

```
$exampleName = $example->exampleName;
if(!$exampleName){
  $exampleName = new ExampleName();
  $exampleName->example_id = $example->id;
}
$exampleName->name = $data['name'];
$exampleName->name_type = $data['name_type'];

$exampleName->save();
```

In this example, it first checks the existence of an associated record, and if found, ignores the initialization. If one is not found, it initializes it, and links it via `example_id` (or however the link is performed). Then, it simply fills in the columns and performs a `save()` operation. Your full code would look like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Example $example){
  $data = $request->validate([
    'account_name' => 'required|string',
    'name'=> 'nullable|string',
    'name_type' =>'nullable|integer',
  ]);

  $example->account_name = $data['account_name'];
  $example->save();

  $exampleName = $example->exampleName;
  if(!$exampleName){
    $exampleName = new ExampleName();
    $exampleName->example_id = $example->id; // Or however you link them
  }
  $exampleName->name = $data['name'];
  $exampleName->name_type = $data['name_type'];

  $exampleName->save();

  $example->load('exampleName');

  return response($example,200);
}
```

Since `$example->exampleName` might still be `null` before the `return` statement, a simple `$example->load()` is called to ensure it is also returned in the JSON response.

Comment: Work like a charm! Thank you!